# Antonym of "having a sense of self-entitlement "

Tags: antonyms

My understanding of "having a sense of self-entitlement" is, in layman's terms: "feel like everything I get, I deserve it. And if anything goes wrong in my life, it certainly isn't my fault"

I have the opposite attitude. "I don't deserve anything if I don't earn it. And if anything goes wrong in my life, it is most likely my fault.

So, what is the antonym of having a sense of self-entitlement?

It can't be as simple as "having no sense of self-entitlement" or "don't have a sense of self-entitlement", or it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few opposites I can think of. The first is having *humility*. An entitled person is likely prideful and expects a great deal because they think they are something special. An appropriately humble person will not feel entitled. This aspect focuses on how the person feels about themselves.

Sometimes we will talk about people like this being very *down to earth*, which emphasizes that their expectations from the world are realistic or modest.

If we are talking about how they interact with other people, we might use a word like *unassuming*. This emphasizes that their interactions with other people don't convey that they feel entitled. On the contrary, they at least interact with others in a way that conveys respect for them. This is a word about how they behave superficially, they may feel inwardly entitled but they don't show it. It's often used when we expect people to feel entitled because we view them as higher than us, but then they interact in a pleasing, humble way.

You can also say that someone doesn't have or doesn't convey a sense of entitlement.

Comment: I edited the question:  Antonym of “having a sense of self-entitlement ” Does it help you to narrow down the choices?

Comment: It doesn't really change things. Overall the closest opposite I can think of is humility but the others could be reasonable in different contexts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humility: Humility is the quality of being humble. Dictionary definitions accentuate humility as a low self-regard and sense of unworthiness

Comment: I think I have to agree "have a sense of humility"  is the opposite of "having a sense of entitlement" because unworthy is an antonym of entitled

Comment: Note that in centuries past, the word "humility" was frequently used in a negative sense (similar to humiliation). In current English, it is almost always considered a positive trait.

Comment: That even better --  a negative sense of polar opposites

Comment: I haven't marked your answer as the accepted answer because the terms you mentioned I myself could also think of. The difficult part is to narrow it down to the one that is closest to the exact opposite. If you can do so, I would accept it

Comment: Doesn't matter to me if you accept it or not. I'm just trying to help. If you don't need help, it also doesn't bother me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110107/discussion-between-tang-ho-and-farnsy).